# Cant persist computed column using deterministic function

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have master detail table and a function to use Sum (Qty * Fee ) and want to use in master table as computed column and persist it , but this error raise, here is my table and function :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1]
(
    [Id] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [INT] NULL,
    [Fee] [MONEY] NULL,
    [T2Id] [BIGINT] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_2]
(
    [Id] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_2] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) 
)

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Test](@Id INT)
RETURNS MONEY
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Total MONEY

    SELECT @Total = CAST(SUM(Qty * Fee) AS MONEY) 
    FROM dbo.Table_1 
    WHERE T2Id = @Id

    RETURN ISNULL(@Total, 0)
END
```

And here is my T-SQL to add `SumRow` and the resulting error:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_2 
    ADD SumRow AS dbo.test(Id) PERSISTED
```

Error:

> Msg 4934, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Computed column 'SumRow' in table 'Table_2' cannot be persisted because the column does user or system data access.

Also this check is true :

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY (OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[test]'),'IsDeterministic')
```

Comment: it is reason as what the error message said `the column does user or system data access` . Your function access a table. Looks like what you need is just to create a `VIEW` joining `Table_1` and `Table_2`

Comment: It is usually best *not* to persist data that can be calculated, unless or until you've demonstrated an actual performance issue. If there is a reason to want to store this calculated value, you might want to consider creating an indexed view, so that SQL Server maintains the data automatically for you.

Comment: There is no need to create an extra column in table2 for this. Just create a view that will calculate the field. If you really must use an extra field for this then the best way of doing this is to create a trigger on table1 for insert/update/delete and calculate and update the new value for table2 there. It will work but will slow table1 down offcourse